# Prove a function is multivalued

Tags: complex-analysis, multivalued-functions

I want to show that the function ((z-1)/(z+1))^(1/4) is multi valued only on the interval [-1,1].

Here's what I'm thinking: pick a point in [-1,1] and show that there exist another point in [-1,1] that will give me the same output. If this is correct how would I show that it is single valued everywhere else?

Comment: The function is multivalued everywhere except for $z=1$, in which it take only the value $0$ and at $z=-1$ at which it is not defined. For every non-zero complex number you have four $4$-th roots.

Comment: Your argument is for showing that a function is not one to one!

Comment: you seem to have a different meaning of "function" than the rest of the world.